# Do apps with in-app purchases remember retrieved product information?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, in-app-purchase

We are working on an app with in-app purchases. Is it okay to store retrieved product information so the data displays faster when the app loads again?

Comment: I think it is fine, if your product information is not going to change, like it price or description, etc.

Answer (score 0):

What if Apple decides to change the price of each tier (as it did a few months ago) with no notifications? I think you should cache your product information to show your products immediately but always start an asynchronous call to retrieve fresh data.